# iPhone sdk- Save Last Selected Date in KALViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I have used KALViewcontroller API to display calendar in my iPhone app. I want to save the last selected date and display it as 'highlighted' when the calendar appears again.
Currently it shows Today's date.

in **KALViewController.m** a function *-(void)showAndSelectToday* is responsible to show today's date and highlight today's tile.

```
[[self calendarView] selectTodayIfVisible];

//where *calendarView* is
- (KalView*)calendarView 
{ 
    checkDateConf = TRUE; 
    checkDate = FALSE; 
    return (KalView*)self.view; 
}
```

In **KalView.m**

```
[gridView selectTodayIfVisible];
```

//Where gridView is KalGridView gridView;

In **KALGridView.m**

*selectTodayIfVisible* is declared

```
- (void)selectTodayIfVisible
{
  KalTileView *todayTile = [frontMonthView todaysTileIfVisible];
  if (todayTile)
    self.selectedTile = todayTile;
}
```

Please guide me how I will highlight selected date.

Answer (score 1):

TO detect which date is selected, I've done this way:

in KalViewController look for didSelectDate (delegate Method) and add Notification post.

```
#pragma mark KalViewDelegate protocol

    - (void)didSelectDate:(KalDate *)date
    {
  //NSLog(@"DID select DATE:%@",date);
  self.selectedDate = [date NSDate];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DATA_SELECTED" object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date]];
  NSDate *from = [[date NSDate] cc_dateByMovingToBeginningOfDay];
  NSDate *to = [[date NSDate] cc_dateByMovingToEndOfDay];
  [self clearTable];
  [dataSource loadItemsFromDate:from toDate:to];
  [tableView reloadData];
  [tableView flashScrollIndicators];
}
```

Then in your view Controller that use Kal receive this post just like:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(userSelectDate:) name:@"DATA_SELECTED" object:nil];
```

and the method called is:

```
-(void)userSelectDate:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSLog(@"date selected:%@",[notification object]);
}
```